# Проблема соединения с локальным OPC сервером WCF сервиса на IIS

Tags: c#, iis, iis-express, opc

Мое приложение в виде WCF сервиса работает с локальным OPC сервером. При тестировании и отладке  в MSVS 2015 на IIS Express все работает отлично и соединение с сервером устанавливается.

После размещения сервиса на виндовом ISS соединение с сервером перестает устанавливаться приходит минутный таймаут. 
Причем функции типа

```
    public bool TestConnection()
    {
         return true;
    }
```

Срабатывают и возвращают значения.
Но функции типа:

```
    public bool OPCConnect()
    {
         Opc.URL url;
         Opc.Da.Server server;
         OpcCom.Factory fact = new OpcCom.Factory();
         server = new Opc.Da.Server(fact,null);
         url = new Opc.URL("opcda://localhost/servername");

         // Connect не происходит здесь
         server.Connect(url, new Opc.ConnectData(new System.Net.NetworkCredential()));

         ...

         return true;
    }
```

Что может быть не так в чем принципиальная разница между IIS и IIS Express?